# Marklogic search: only output the matching element(s) and the uri of a document using jsearch

Tags: marklogic

I'm new to MarkLogic. I'm looking for a way to only output the matching element(s) from a document when using jsearch, but the element to with the searched term has a match is not known when executing the query. Let me illustrate:

```
jsearch.documents()
  .where(cts.wordQuery('mark'))
  .result();
```

This gives me all documents containing 'mark', e.g.

```
{
  "results": [
  {
    "index": 0, 
    "uri": "/books/twain4.json", 
    "score": 14336, 
    "confidence": 0.432453483343124, 
    "fitness": 0.7490314245224, 
    "document": {
      "title": "Adventures of Huckleberry Finn", 
      "author": "Mark Twain", 
      "edition": {
        "format": "hardback", 
        "price": 18
        }
      , 
       "synopsis": "The adventures of Huck, a boy of 13, and Jim, an escaped slave, rafting down the Mississippi River in pre-Civil War America."
    }
  }
  , ...
```

However, I'd like to know how I can adjust the query so that it gives only the matching element(s) per document where a match is found:

```
{
  "results": [
  {
    "index": 0, 
    "uri": "/books/twain4.json", 
    "score": 14336, 
    "confidence": 0.432453483343124, 
    "fitness": 0.7490314245224, 
    "document": {
      "author": "Mark Twain", 
    }
  }
  , ...
```

Only the author element has a match here, but this element is not known at the time of executing the query. I'd like to display only the matching value for author like above. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You have a few options here.

If you'd like to run a search using jSearch against only one JSON property, you can run the following:

```
const jsearch = require('/MarkLogic/jsearch');
const term = 'mark';
const query = cts.jsonPropertyWordQuery('author', term);
jsearch.documentSelect(cts.search(query), { snippet: { query: query } });
```

If you'd like to control how what gets returned by jSearch, you can apply [extraction](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/javascript#id_19052):

```
const jsearch = require('/MarkLogic/jsearch');
const term = 'mark';
jsearch.documents().where(cts.wordQuery(term))
.map({ extract: { paths: ['/author'] }})
.result();
```

You can also combine the two:

```
const jsearch = require('/MarkLogic/jsearch');
const term = 'mark';
const query = cts.jsonPropertyWordQuery('author', term);
jsearch.documentSelect(cts.search(query), { snippet: { query: query }, extract: { paths: ['/author'] } });
```

For more information you can read the following documentation: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/javascript#id_71243

(One more note: you may also want to be interested in running a Query By Example - where you build a prototype document and execute a search based on that. More information here: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/javascript#id_60216

Comment: One footnote on Tamas's good advice: the map() postprocessor can provide a {snippet: ...} specification, removing the need for a separate documentSelect() call.  See: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/javascript#id_71243

Comment: What if I don't know in advance that the match for my word 'mark' is going to be on the element 'author' in some document.